# How to rewrite subsites with parameter to html only

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

My old website has a url like "/index.php?s=subsite" and "/?s=subsite".
Now I added the following lines to ".htaccess" file, to make them shorter:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(html)?$ index.php?s=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Open a site with "/subsite.html" works fine, but also the old url "/index.php?s=subsite" and "/?s=subsite" works too. Is there a way, to allow "/subsite.html" only and redirect the old requests to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(?:index\.php)?\?s=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ /index.php?s=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule to your htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?s=([^& \]+)&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html?%2 [L,R=301]
```

This matches against the request, tries to capture the `s` query string parameter, then redirects the browser to that parameter followed by an ".html" and the rest of any query string that was there.